# Using null as an identifier

Tags: javascript, syntax, null

Any attempt to create an identifier with the name "null" would be unsuccessful.

```
var null = 5;
```

But the interpreter won't be confused if your try to write something like this:

```
var myObject = { name: "Just a name", null: "Just a null-property value"};
```

So are object's property names identifiers?

Comment: identifiers are not the same as property names

Comment: I am actually a little surprised that works. According to the MDN "property must be a valid JavaScript identifier" and null is not. Edit: it appears you need to follow the syntax rules but reserved words are allowed.

Comment: @dlsso Believe property name is converted to `String`

Comment: @guest271314 If that's the case why I can't a give an object a property `1st`?

Comment: @dlsso `var myObject = { name: "Just a name", "1st": "Just a null-property value"}`

Comment: But you enclosed it in quotes. No surprises there. In the case of keywords, you can do just as the OP indicated, no quotes and the reserved words still work. In that case `1st` would not work.

Comment: @dlsso Is `1st` a `Number` or a `String`?

Comment: My point exactly. It's neither. It's not valid. I don't expect it to work. But neither is `break` which is why I was surprised that it does work.

Comment: Though `1st` can be a property name when a string or template string. `var n = 1st` would return `Unexpected identifier`. Do not believe `1st` is a reserved word

Comment: JavaScript automatically converts object keys into strings. So you could add single quote, double quotes, or no quotes and it will work. Yes. Even reserved works. Although I would not advise doing so.

Comment: @andremcgruder if it converted keys to strings `var myObject = { 1st: "foo" }` would work, but it doesn't.